# When i run two programs in parallel, the run tabs are jumping based on the output

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, i run jetty application in one run and rest tests in another run. I would like to watch the rest tests during their run, however on every console output of the jetty application, intellij moves to the jetty tab automatically.
How can i make it static, so it will stay on the chosen tab?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, did you report that?

Comment: are you sure? i think its default behavior. Talked to a colleague, he told me he set this up, but he doesn't remember how.

Comment: Well, there is an option: Run/Debug Configuration | Logs | Show console when standard out changes